# Xamarin.iOS Storyboards A-B-C-A Navigation - How to?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, uistoryboardsegue, xcode-storyboard, unwind-segue

I've built a storyboard with multiple ViewControllers for my Xamarin.iOS application to set a foundation for my application (mainly showing tables, overviews and detail-views). I'm using segues and I invoke the PerformSegue(...) method to push a new ViewController to the stack. This works properly, and honestly I like the navigation system very much.

I am running into a problem that seems easy to fix at first sight, but after spending half a day I couldn't for the life of me find out what approach I should take:

My navigation is set up like this:
**(1) Menu page (tableview)** *-> segue ->* **(2) BarcodeScanner** *-> segue ->* **(3) Detail page**

I want the user to be able to navigate from (3) Detail page back to (1) Menu page. This includes not seeing the (2) "Barcode scanner" title but the (1) "Menu" Title in the "back button" text on the (3) Detail page. I want it to be skipped.

In Windows Phone and Android projects I would just clear the 'backstack' or pop an entry from the navigation stack, but in iOS this seems to work differently. Am I overseeing a simple solution for this, or does something so trivial require more work than I thought?

(Note: I'm not using Xamarin Forms)

Comment: Are you familiar with the unwind segue?  This Xamarin recipe explains it pretty well, and I think it's exactly what you need: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/general/storyboard/unwind_segue/

Comment: @DylanS Yes I am. This does exactly what you say it does - it unwinds the navigation stack. The problem that I have is that when I get to the (3) Detail page I want to have (2) Barcodescanner removed. Why? So that I see "< Menu" in the left top when on the (3) Detail page, rather than < BarcodeScanner. Basically I want to remove the (2) BarcodeScanner from the backstack as soon as (3) Detail page is being loaded....

Comment: Oh I think I see what you're saying.  Is the back button referenced the UINavigationController's back button?  And this is all in a UINavigationController?

Comment: @DylanS I have one RootNavigationController, and from there I segue into other views (some from code, some from a litteral button click). Every time a new viewcontroller is opened, the title of the previous viewcontroller is visible under the " < Back button " title. It does this all automatically, without any interaction from my side. Going back also works, but obviously I want the second step gone...

Comment: Ahhh.  I haven't tried this, but I suspect it's possible to use the UINavigationController's ViewController property (it's an array of the navigation stack) and remove the middle ViewController.  Inside of ViewController 3, you'd access the array `this.NavigationController.ViewControllers` and modify it to remove ViewController 2, then set `this.NavigationController.ViewControllers` to the updated array.

Comment: I think the problem is that he shouldn't be using PerformSegue because it displays controllers modally on top of the stack, and Push them using NavigationController.PushViewController(), making sure controller 1 is your rootcontroller then when you want to pop all the controllers and go back to your first screen you can use NavigationController.PopToRootViewController().